# have the difference between 2 dates dynamically

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I don't know if my problem has already been asked on the forum but I haven't found any answers.

I have the following table:

| Transaction | Operation number | Opération number_2 | Date opération |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1223 | 080 | 080 | 11/02/2023 |
| 1223 | 010 | 010 | 07/04/2022 |
| 1223 | 020 | 020 | 20/04/2022 |
| 1223 | 0150 | 0150 | 12/08/2023 |

The user can choose different operations through two filters (Operation number and Operation number_1) in order to obtain the difference in days between the 2 selected operations.

For example if the user filters on operation number = 080 and another filters on operation number_1 = 010, the calculation would be 11/02/2023 - 07/04/2022

How can I carry out this calculation using a Dax formula please?

Thanks

I need à Dax formula to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

If the two slicer tables have a relationship to the main table then you can use:

```
OpDiff = 
  var d1 = CALCULATE(MIN(Op[Date opération]), REMOVEFILTERS('OpNumber2'))
  var d2 = CALCULATE(MIN(Op[Date opération]), REMOVEFILTERS('OpNumber1'))
  RETURN DATEDIFF(d1, d2, DAY)
```

If no relationship, then you can use:

```
OpDiff2 = 
  var d1 = CALCULATE(MIN(Op[Date opération]), Op[Operation number] = SELECTEDVALUE(OpNumber1[Operation number]))
  var d2 = CALCULATE(MIN(Op[Date opération]), Op[Operation number] = SELECTEDVALUE(OpNumber2[Opération number_2]))
  RETURN DATEDIFF(d1, d2, DAY)
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your feedback.

In fact I created the columns operation number and operation number_1 which are exactly the same columns, so that the user can filter between 2 operations and thus obtain the diff date between xes 2 operations.

I will test your DAX formulas and get back to you.